# Android set style rule of parent element based on child element value

Tags: android, android-layout

Given this layout named relLayoutWrap.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/priorityView"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/statusCheckBox"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/StatusLabel" >
   </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I would like to apply a different background color to the relative layout parent element based on the value of the TextView element.

The value of the textview element can change as I inflate/recycle the view.  Ie.:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
RelativeLayout itemLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.relLayoutWrap,null);
final TextView priorityView = (TextView) itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.priorityView);

priorityView.setText("yes");  //or sometimes "no"
```

So basically if the value of the TextView is "yes" I want the RelativeLayouts background color to be yellow, and if its "no" I would like the background color to be blue.  Is this possible purely through xml style rules?  Or do I have to manually set the background color as this value changes programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, the best way to do this would be to set the color yourself.

As far as I know, there isn't a way to do this with XML, as in conditionally check the text and then change the color based on the text. You could possibly have two different XMLs for the button and go about it that way, but it doesn't really seem needed here.

In my code, I have something similar to this, except I have a lot more things to change than just color. For me, I do something like this...

```
public static final int STATUS_CODE_YES = 1;
public static final int STATUS_CODE_NO = 2;

. . . 

if(something something something) {
    //I need to set the state to Yes!
    updateTextView(STATUS_CODE_YES);
} else {
    //I need to set the state to no...
    updateTextView(STATUS_CODE_NO);
}

. . . 


public void updateTextView(int status) {
switch(status) {
    case STATUS_CODE_YES:
        textView.setText("Yes");
        textView.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        //a lot more stuff here
        break;
    case STATUS_CODE_NO: 
        textView.setText("No");
        textView.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        //a lot more stuff here
        break; 
    default:
        System.out.println("You did something wrong here...ERROR");
        break;
}
```

This system works very well for me. Technically, I guess there are probably ways to do this through XML, but they don't really apply well for this situation.

Comment: ahhh.  spoiled by web stylez :`(
this makes sense now that I think about it.